# HP Proliant Servers - WMI query for system health

Tags: windows, monitoring, hardware, hp, health

I want to query lots of HP servers to determine their overall health. I don't want to use any packages, or even SNMP - I want to query the server health from WMI and understand if a box is Green/Amber/Red - just like the HP Management Home Page.

This MUST be possible - but I can't find any documentation...

Oh yes, and the servers are running Windows Server 2003/8.

Help!!

Mike

Answer (score 7):

I was having a hell of a time getting HP to give me a WMI namespace for any of my Proliant machines.  I followed tons of dead ends and finally ended up here!

Installing the **HP Insight Management WBEM Providers** will automatically give a **HPQ** WMI namespace with all information within!  Use WMI Explorer to see whats in there. Done!

Answer (score 1):

Why not just get HP Systems Insight Manager (SIM), I know you don't want to use an packages but it's a seriously powerful, if overcomplex, system.

Comment: Great suggestion, but we want to integrate the results of the health check into another tool.

Answer (score 1):

I hate to say it, but using the HP SNMP tools is probably the best way to do it.

I do believe that with the HP "Systems Management Homepage" is installed that the full health details should be available via WBEM, not sure about anything else.

Our HP kit all runs either Debian Linux or VMWare ESXi, SNMP for the former WBEM for the latter.

Comment: Hi LapTop6, Yes, agreed - I'm hoping that installing the HP sysmgmt stuff will indeed add/expose WBEM counters which can then be exposed via WMI and in turn my little .NET app/Powershell script.

Answer (score 1):

WMI is very powerful and relatively easy to use once you've ascended the learning slopes. You're going to have to write scripts though.I use VBScript but you can do most of what you need in Powershell these days.

Start at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974579.aspx

JR

Comment: Hi JR. No prob using/coding/scripting WMI/WBEM - I just don't know the right counters to access - they seem to be lost in some random HP documents somewhere.... But I'm very sure they exist..

Comment: Search www.microsoft.com/downloads for "WMI Administrative Tools". These allow you to browse the various counters. They have fairly obvious names, so it isn't hard to pick out the ones you want. When I last looked a an HP it didn't provide any custom WMI classes, which is a bit surprising since even cheap Dells do.

Answer (score 1):

I like Microsoft's Script-o-matic for finding/scripting WMI counters.

Get it here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=09dfc342-648b-4119-b7eb-783b0f7d1178&displaylang=en